# Is the question ok here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am interested in the answer to the following question:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74049/mathematical-model-for-a-webpage-layout

( Mathematical model for a webpage layout? - asking for tool or formal language to specify webpage layout in a "mathematical" way )

Is it ok to post it Programmers ?

**EDIT**: If so, can it be migrated or should I repost?

**EDIT 2**: Question caused some interest, but has been put on hold as "too broad". Is there any way it can be reformulated to get at least one answer?
Should another question be asked or is it better to rewrite the old one?

Yes, there are some proposals here in comments. For example, Stack Exchange network is about learning. So, in which mode should I ask a question here to learn about practical and ultracompact physics/geometry formalization of HTML/CSS or at least to learn there is no such thing, given I already know some GUI builders (like for wxWidgets, ALM and Tcl/Tk) do have comprehensible models?

Why is it called "shopping recommendation"? For example, if I will ask about stable external sorting n*log(n) algorithm for functional programming language, will it be called shopping and as well "too broad"?

Comment: software and off-site resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: I believe mine goes under "conceptual questions about software development" though.

Comment: per my reading it seems to fall under software recommendations as written here: "asking for tool or formal language to..." Your question [at main site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/266554/31260) seems to use different but similar wording: "I have found no sources, books, articles, guides, tools, which would <satisfy particular requirements>. Does such a thing even exist..."

Comment: I thought more about algorithms and domain specific languages as I am not aware of even a single implementation to seek software recomendations.

Comment: And if nor this site, neither webmasters, what is the right place then? Theoretical Computer Science seem a bit too far?

Comment: well site visitors can't read your mind, they can only see what is in the question. If question reads different from what you intended, consider editing it to better match. As long as is reads as seeking off-site resource recommendation, it's unlikely to fit any SE site I'm afraid. ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @Gnat: Feel free to post your first comment as an answer.

Comment: @JimG. for the question [asked and edited at main site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/266554/revisions "as of rev 3-4"), mentioned comment would be insufficient. As of now, this meta question rather relates to guidance given in [What is needed to really fix a question (an Atwood transform)](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6744/31260)

Comment: @Gnat: thanks for editing the question! BTW, I do not understand why the question is closed as "too broad" and there are still no answers to it?

Comment: reasons to close as too broad are [described in details here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490). Those who voted to close probably felt that these somehow apply, although I can't tell for sure (you can see that I am not listed among them)

Comment: Well, I can see the question is on the border of off-topic, but too broad or too long seems to be wrong reason. BTW, trying luck on CS: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35490/mathematical-model-for-a-webpage-layout where it seems to fit better.